# why is app using "/layout-mdpi" eventhough phone display is "Normal-XHDPI"

Tags: android, android-layout

I came across this strange layout behavior today as I was fixing a bug...

I have four layouts in :

- /res/layout/my.xml
- /res/layout-large-hdpi/my.xml
- /res/layout-mdpi/my.xml
- /res/layout-sw600dp-mdpi/my.xml

The phone I'm using is a Samsung Note 2 (my favorite test device) and to obtain the screen information I use the app "[ScreenInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo)"

**Question:** I was totally expecting the layout in /res/layout to be used because I haven't defined a layout that matches the XHDPI criteria, but instead the layout from /res/layout-mdpi was used ! Why ? It makes no sense to me.

Please see the attached image of the app below :

[image: ScreenInfo on Note 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Layouts that are in `/res/layout/` are only used when there is absolutely no layouts that matches the criteria involved. The system is going to look for the most detailed folder it can pull the resource from based on the provided qualifiers.  So if you had a `/res/layout-sw600dp-xhdpi/` folder,it will check for the resource in there first.  Then it will go to `/res/layout-xhdpi/` folder.  If it can't find it in there, it will move down the `dpi` folders until the last resort is the most general `/res/layout/` folder.

In this case, there is no `-xhdpi` folder. There is a `-large-hdpi` folder, but the phone doesn't match the `-large` qualifier, so it skips it. There is no `-hdpi` folder. There is a `-mdpi` folder, so it checks for the resource there.  It finds it, so it uses it.

Comment: Great! thanks for that explanation - I thought the whole process worked on exact layout folder names. It makes sense to me now; an mdpi layout would fit inside an hdpi (or better) screen.

Comment: A far better and more detailed explanation is here. The process is actually much more complex than what I stated. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: For me this is very unintuitive, I have one particular layout that needs to be different for mdpi devices, meaning I need a 'layout-mdpi' folder with 1 file, and a 'layout-hpdi' with every other file, rather than just being able to leave those files in the regular layout folder!